# Eclipse UML2 Reverse Engineer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Can someone please help me reverse engineerJava code in Eclipse using UML2? Or give links to tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can help you.

[Generating Code From UML With Eclipse](http://blog.lebrijo.com/?p=170&language=en)

[UML with Eclipse Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html)

[Getting Started with UML2](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/docs/articles/Getting_Started_with_UML2/article.html)